# XGBoostError: rabit/internal/utils.h:90: Allreduce failed - Error while attempting XGboost on Dask Fargate Cluster in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, dask, xgboost, aws-fargate, dask-distributed

**Overview**: I'm trying to run an XGboost model on a bunch of parquet files sitting in S3 using dask by setting up a fargate cluster and connecting it to a Dask cluster.

Total dataframe size totals to about 140 GB of data. I scaled up a fargate cluster with properties:

- Workers: 39
- Total threads: 156
- Total memory: 371.93 GiB

So there should be enough data to hold the data tasks. Each worker has 9+ GB with 4 Threads. I do some very basic preprocessing and then I create a DaskDMatrix which does cause the task bytes per worker to get a little high, but never above the threshold where it would fail.

Next I run `xgb.dask.train` which utilizes the xgboost package not the dask_ml.xgboost package. Very quickly, the workers die and I get the error `XGBoostError: rabit/internal/utils.h:90: Allreduce failed`. When I attempted this with a single file with only 17MB of data, I would still get this error but only a couple workers die. Does anyone know why this happens since I have double the memory of the dataframe?

```
X_train = X_train.to_dask_array()
X_test = X_test.to_dask_array()
y_train = y_train
y_test = y_test

dtrain = xgb.dask.DaskDMatrix(client,X_train, y_train)

output = xgb.dask.train(
client,
{"verbosity": 1, "tree_method": "hist", "objective": "reg:squarederror"},
dtrain,
num_boost_round=100,
evals=[(dtrain, "train")])
```